# How to set permission to ftp-user so that has FTP access to /home/another-user/www/public_html folder?

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, vsftpd

I'm a novice with Linux/Unix.  Basically I'm attempting to setup a Web server, and FTP server on a Linux box via SSH.

My plan is to have Apache's root folder inside the main user account like

`/home/giuseppe/www/public_html`

and have an ftp-user account which should have `rw-` access via FTP to `/home/giuseppe/www/public_html`

I'm still not able to have the `ftp-user` being able to access the `public_html` directory in the home folder of the other account.

When I connect via FTP using the `ftp-user`, it defaults to its home directory.

These are the steps I have taken so far:

- I have installed `vsftpd` and edited `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.config` ports and so on so that I'm able to connect with the `ftp-user` account. I've also set the `local_root=/home/giuseppe/www/public_html/`
- I have restarted the `vsftpd` service after any config changes.
- I have added a group named `developers`
- I have made `ftp-user` member of `developers`, so that `id ftp-user` gives:

  `uid=500(ftp-user) gid=502(developers) groups=502(developers)`
- I've changed the group of `public_html` with `chgrp developers /home/giuseppe/www/public_html/`

However, every time I connect via FTP the `ftp-user` account has rw- access to its own home folder only.

As I test I have added a symlink `ln -s /home/giuseppe/www/public_html /home/ftp-user/`.  While I can see the symlink in the `ftp-user` home directory, I'm not able to navigate through the `public_html` symlink. Here is Filezilla's status log when I double click the symlink:

```
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    CWD /home/ftp-user
Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
Command:    CWD public_html
Response:   550 Failed to change directory.
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Starting download of /home/ftp-user/public_html
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,4,14).
Command:    RETR public_html
Response:   550 Failed to open file.
Error:  Critical error
```

Is my planned setup sensible or would you setup things differently?

Comment: I suppose it would be safe to assume that you `chmod`'d the directory, but it would be nice to see what permissions the folder has with an `ls -l`.

Comment: Yes I did give group permission and ls -l would have given drwxrwx--- 5 giuseppe developers 4096 Aug 27 01:30 public_html

Comment: Since the post I have changed my plan and eventually got things working. I have chroot() in vsftpd.config, then I have mounted the ftp-user home directory to the /home/giuseppe/www/public_html. I have then also mounted the /var/www/html to /home/giuseppe/www/public_html. Then I have made apache user and apache group drwxrwx of /home/giuseppe/www/public_html, and finally added ftp-user to the apache group. This seems to work, I've got hints from Apache docs where it mentions using mountpoints.